# How to pass multiple locations via URL to Google Maps native app?

Tags: android, google-maps, hyperlink, native

I would like to open Google Maps native app through an URL via my own native application.

This is possible as shown in following page:
http://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/

through following URL:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/760+W+Genesee+St+Syracuse+NY+13204/314+Avery+Ave+Syracuse+NY+13204/9090+Destiny+USA+Dr+Syracuse+NY+13204

This url opens correctly in the browser.

However, when opened via Google Maps native app, the first location is filled in correctly while all the others are cropped into the second location and give an error accordingly.

Question: Is there a workaround to pass multiple locations via URL to Google Maps native app?